# Replace substring in string with variable named as substring?

Tags: replace

Could you help me with something?

In a frontend template, I'm trying to go through the string, find all substrings between double curly brackets `{{ something }}` using regular expressions and replace them with field values that have the substring in the name. I want it to work dynamically.

i.e. replace string `{{ something }}` with value of field `{{ entry.something }}`, replace string `{{ something-else }}` with value of field `{{ entry.something-else }}` ...etc.

I tried the replace filter, and I'm able to find the strings between curly brackets, but I don't know how to replace them with actual fields values.

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like you'd be better off using [Yii's Message Translations](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/tutorial-i18n#message-formatting) for this, if that's possible in your situation. They are what powers Craft's `|t` / `|translate` filter:

```
{{ "String with {something} and {somethingElse}"|t('site', entry) }}
```

With this, `{something}` and `{somethingElse}` would be replaced with the string values of `entry.something` and `entry.somethingElse`.

You can also pass an array for more complex substitutions:

```
{{ "String with {something} and {somethingElse}"|t('site', {
    something: entry.something,
    somethingElse: entry.somethingElse,
}) }}
```